# create a dynamic url in pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I declared a variable called "name". Once the user clicks on the form , it should call the function myFunction which assigns the value that the user types to the variable name. For instance if the user types "John". the url would be localhost:5000/profile/John. But I am getting document.getElementById("username") is undefined.

```
-let name = "gg";    
    //- -function enteringName() {
    //-      - name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    //- -};

    <h1>Log in</h1>
    <form action="/profile/#{name}"  method="POST" id="loginForm" onclick="#{myFunction()}" >
      <label for="username">username:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
      <br />
      <label for="password">password:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
      <br />
    </form>
    <p>

      <a href="http://localhost:3000/registration">register here</a>
    </p>
    <script>

function myFunction() {
 -name = document.getElementById("username").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. There were some problems with pug indentation. Also pug is only server rendering html, but on client side you should set name to element by js. Tested this code in codepen, take a look there too https://codepen.io/aidonline01/pen/rNOwWJY :)

```pug
-let name = "gg";
//- -function enteringName() {
//-      - name = document.getElementById("username").value;
//- -};

<h1>Log in 1</h1>
  <form action="/profile/#{name}"  method="POST" id="loginForm" onclick="myFunction()" >
    <label for="username">username:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    <br />
    <label for="password">password:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <br />
  </form>
<p>

<a href="http://localhost:3000/registration">register here</a>
</p>
script
  .
    function myFunction() {
      #{name} = document.getElementById("username").value;
      document.getElementById("loginForm").action = `/profile/${#{name}}`;
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of passing the name of the variable from Pug to the client-side javascript? If you replaced `#{name}` with `foo` it would work just the same.

Comment: I dunno, but isn't it a part of a question?

Comment: #{name} holds the value whatever I store in name